# Check once in the loop

Tags: c#

The following code calculate the nearest distance in two points.
The part `if(j==0)` is tested redundantly for  UsedServices.Count-1 time, 
is there any way not to introduce this redudancy?
Of course we can separate the case out from for loop, I am just thinking is there a more elegant way to achieve this.

```
double[] nearestDistant=new double[UnUsedServices.Count];

for (int i=0;i<UnUsedServices.Count;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<UsedServices.Count;j++)
    {
        double distance=GetDistance(UnUsedServices[i].coords, 
                                    UsedServices[j].coords);

        if (j==0) //Used once and redundant for UsedServices.Count-1 time!
        {
            nearestDistant[i] = distance;
        }
        else
        {
            nearestDistant[i] = Math.Min(nearestDistant[i], distance);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could initialize `nearestDistant[i]` to [`Double.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue.aspx) before the inner loop and then you can remove the `if`.

The side effect of this is when `UsedServices.Count == 0` the `nearestDistant[i]` would be set to `Double.MaxValue`. If that's ok with you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about expression evaluation and branch prediction then don't worry about it - leave it up to the compiler to optimise it.

If you are looking to streamline it code-wise, then the ['?' ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is an option:

```
nearestDistant[i] = j == 0 ? distance : Math.Min(nearestDistant[i], distance);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<UnUsedServices.Count;i++)
{
    if(UsedServices.Count > 0)
    {
      double distance=GetDistance(UnUsedServices[i].coords, UsedServices[0].coords);
       nearestDistant[i] = distance;
    }

    for(int j=1;j<UsedServices.Count;j++)
    {
        double distance=GetDistance(UnUsedServices[i].coords, UsedServices[j].coords);

        nearestDistant[i] = Math.Min(nearestDistant[i], distance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about initialising nearestDistant[i] to a number far greater than any distance value before entering the 'j' loop. Then you can use

```
 double[] nearestDistant=new double[UnUsedServices.Count];

for(int i=0;i<UnUsedServices.Count;i++)
            {

            nearestDistant[i] = <A REALLY HUGE NUMBER>

            for(int j=0;j<UsedServices.Count;j++)
            {
                double distance=GetDistance(UnUsedServices[i].coords, UsedServices[j].coords);

                nearestDistant[i] = Math.Min(nearestDistant[i], distance);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Double.MaxValue` is a REALLY HUGE number. Cannot get any bigger.